# Will go test code only referenced in test files be compiled into the binary?

Tags: testing, go, compilation

I am wondering what code will be compiled into the go binary if you compile a binary using `go build ./...` . This will compile a binary that has a cli program. For this cli program, I have test code and non test code. I currently have several flavours of test code:

- `foo_test.go` in package `foo_test`
- `foo_internal_test.go` in package `foo`
- `testutil.go` in package `testutil` that provides test utility functions

No test code is actually referenced in the non test code. The testutil functions are only imported in the test files.

If the test code is infact compiled into the binary , how much of a problem is this?

Comment: What binary are you referring to? If you're not building a test binary, you're not compiling `*_test.go` files, so they're not just eliminated during linking, they're never compiled at all.

Comment: I hopefully clarified the question

Comment: `*_test.go` files are only included by the `go test` command, in the named package. They are never even _seen_ by the compiler otherwise.

Comment: BTW, you can't compile a binary with `go build ./...`, that is building all the packages included in the wildcard, then discarding all the compiled objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A go binary only includes code reachable from its `main()` entry point. For test binaries `main()` is the test runner.

As to "how much of a problem" it is if it were included... none. It would increase the binary size and compilation time somewhat but otherwise have no impact - code that isn't executed, by definition, does nothing.

Comment: Interesting edge case is when using helper functions for testing. These helpers can import additional packages. It might make significant difference to size of prod vs testing code when you have test only dependencies. I agree, Go should eliminate all dead code. But it would be nice to be explicit about this rather then rely on magic.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that if you have an init() function in an otherwise unreachable file, it will still be linked into the executable.

_test.go files would be still excluded.

This bit us when we had some test helper code that was not in _test files. One had an init() function which ran on the executable startup.